# How can I get capabilities to work with su?

Tags: security, su

I added a line to `/etc/security/capability.conf` so I can have a user who can read everything for backups, but not do everything root can.

```
cap_dac_read_search backup
```

If I add a password and shell for the user and then login, then I get the inherited capability:

```
backup$ capsh --print
Current: = cap_dac_read_search+i
```

But it doesn't show up when I `su` to the account:

```
user$ sudo su backup -s /bin/sh -c "capsh --print"
Current: =
```

Naturally it works for `sudo` or `su` to root:

```
user$ sudo capsh --print
Current: = cap_chown,cap_dac_override, ...
```

Is there a way to get the capabilities transferred when using `su`?

Comment: What about `sudo -iu backup capsh --print`?

Answer (score 2):

Install `libpam-cap`

In `/etc/pam.d/su`, make sure that `pam_cap.so` appears *before* `pam_rootok.so`

```
auth       optional  pam_cap.so
auth       sufficient pam_rootok.so
```

You've already got `capability.conf` set up, so then you'll be good to go!